# Как в select автоматически выбрать option текущего месяца из списка месяцев?

Tags: javascript, html, select

Например если сейчас месяц июнь, то как сделать чтобы в select сразу был выбран июнь?

```
    var Month;
Data = new Date();
Month = Data.getMonth();

if (Month==5) {
  
}

    <SELECT>
<OPTION value=1>Январь
<OPTION value=2>Февраль
<OPTION value=3>Март
<OPTION value=4>Апрель
<OPTION value=5>Май
<OPTION value=6>Июнь
<OPTION value=7>Июль
<OPTION value=8>Август
<OPTION value=9>Сентябрь
<OPTION value=10>Октябрь
<OPTION value=11>Ноябрь
<OPTION value=12>Декабрь</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легко и просто, берём текущий месяц, добавляем + 1 т.к. у вас в атрибутах `value`, числа начинают отсчитываться с цифры 1, селектим этот селектор через [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) и выбираем атрибут через [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```js
document.querySelector(`option[value="${new Date().getMonth()+1}"]`)
    .setAttribute('selected', 'true')
```

```html
<SELECT>
<OPTION value=1>Январь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=2>Февраль</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3>Март</OPTION>
<OPTION value=4>Апрель</OPTION>
<OPTION value=5>Май</OPTION>
<OPTION value=6>Июнь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=7>Июль</OPTION>
<OPTION value=8>Август</OPTION>
<OPTION value=9>Сентябрь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=10>Октябрь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=11>Ноябрь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=12>Декабрь</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

##### По рекомендации @AlexeyTen:

```js
document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex = new Date().getMonth()
```

```html
<SELECT>
<OPTION value=1>Январь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=2>Февраль</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3>Март</OPTION>
<OPTION value=4>Апрель</OPTION>
<OPTION value=5>Май</OPTION>
<OPTION value=6>Июнь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=7>Июль</OPTION>
<OPTION value=8>Август</OPTION>
<OPTION value=9>Сентябрь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=10>Октябрь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=11>Ноябрь</OPTION>
<OPTION value=12>Декабрь</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Вообще лучше не выбирать конкретный option, просто присвоить значение select-у.

Comment: @3vgeny просто добавьте к селектору с option `#select`, типа такого: `document.querySelector(\`#select8 option[value="${new Date().getMonth()+1}"]\`).setAttribute('selected', 'true')`

Comment: @AlexeyTen согласен, и в html-е меньше мусора будет.

Comment: Извиняюсь что я такой нуб, но у меня это не работает, возможно не подключен jquery или что-то такое. В интернете этот код работает а у меня почему то нет, даже если создаю новый чистый файл html

Comment: @3vgeny а вы подключили js файл?

Comment: @3vgeny также причина проблемы может быть, если вы к примеру подключили сначала JS файл в `<head>`, а нужно в конец `<body>` чтобы html подгрузился.

Comment: <body>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
 var Month;
Data = new Date();
Month = Data.getMonth();
alert(Month);
document.querySelector(`option[value="${new Date().getMonth()+1}"]`).setAttribute('selected', 'true');

</SCRIPT>
 <select> ... </select>

Comment: @3vgeny как в воду глядел, так оно и есть, нужно скрипты перенести в конец `<body>`, пример: `<html><head></head><body><!-- какой-то код --><script src="kakauto-script.js"></body></html>`

Comment: Ладно буду пробовать, пока туплю ) Не работает и всё, хотя сначала <html><body> потом как обычно <script src=""> тут весь кода и ваш тоже потом </script> потом <select> ... </select> потом </body></html>

Comment: @3vgeny Вы наверное не прочитали мои комментарии, перескажу только намного точнее, сначала вы должны написать `<select>...</select>`, а только ПОСЛЕ него сами скрипты которые должны запускаться, чтобы весь нужный HTML контент загрузился.

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо большое ) у меня привычка сначала <script> потом html, сделал наоборот заработало

Answer (score 0):

Гораздо проще сделать так:

```
let date = new Date();
document.querySelector('select').value = date.getMonth() + 1;
```

date.getMonth() + 1 делаем потому что нумерация месяцев начинается с 0, а у Вас в списке с 1, в связи с чем, предыдущий месяц будет будет отображаться как текущий.